# How to activate the "other" teleporters in Two Worlds?

Tags: two-worlds

In Two Worlds I, I have no problems to activate the teleporters in the north. But in the south the teleporters look a little bit different and won't activate.

Is there a quest that I need to finish to be able to activate these?